# Discord Ticket Bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

after creating the ticket from client side when problem is resolve how can i save that chat for further proof and even send a copy to client side ?
1.Use of transcript.
2.Save message as html  format
3.Using node js language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the html part, but this is the code I personally use to save any amount of messages in a channel in a .txt file - `(discord.py rewrite v1.4.1)`

```
@client.command(aliases=['transcript', 'save'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def history(ctx, limit: int = 100):
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    messages = await ctx.channel.history(limit=limit).flatten()

    with open(f"{channel}_messages.txt", "a+", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        print(f"\nTranscript Saved by - {ctx.author.display_name}.\n\n", file=f)
        for message in messages:
            embed = ""
            if len(message.embeds) != 0:
                embed = message.embeds[0].description
                print(f"{message.author.name} - {embed}", file=f)
            print(f"{message.author.name} - {message.content}", file=f)
    await ctx.message.add_reaction("✅")
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Transcript saved.")
    history = discord.File(fp=f'{channel}_messages.txt', filename=None)
    await ctx.send(file=history)
```